# Android kotlin crossinline return from lambda

Tags: android, kotlin, inline

Been working with crossinline inline and noinline for while, but never understood crossinline 100% percent. I Did deeper reading and tried to do some coding examples by myself and would like to talk about one situation.

So crossinline disables possibility of adding return to our lambda function (correct me if I'm wrong here). Lets see example:

```
 inline fun higherOrderFunction(lambda : () -> Unit){
    lambda.invoke()
    Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

And I call this function like this:

```
higherOrderFunction {
            print("E Numbers Detector android app is the best")
            return
        }
```

Works fine. Keep in mind that in this case Toast is not executed due to the return that is called.
If I put crossinline on my lambda:

```
 inline fun higherOrderFunction(crossinline lambda : () -> Unit){.......
```

I won't be able to use return in the place that I put it. So it disables return in lambda.
But does it?

What if I do workaround And put lambda code in some other function and add return:

```
 inline fun higherOrderFunction(lambda : () -> Unit){
    lambda.invoke()
    Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

This part up stays the same.
But now I add function:

```
fun testLambdaFunction() {
        print("E Numbers Detector android app is the best")
        return
    }
```

And do the call like this:

```
higherOrderFunction {
            testLambdaFunction()
        }
```

If I do that, everything works fine, Toast is printed and my lambda function has a return in itself even though I use crossinline to disable it.

Why is this so? Isn't this "return" part of our lambda that we sent as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a `return` in `higherOrderFunction()`'s lambda, the function which 'returns' is the `higherOrderFunction()`, while when you `return` in `testLambdaFunction()` the function which 'returns' is just the `testLambdaFunction()` itself. More or less think of `crossinline` as a toggle to whether allow a lambda to end your calling function's execution prematurely or not.

Keep in mind that calls of functions with `inline` keyword no longer exist after compilation. What basically happens is that their body is being copy-pasted to their previous function call (not precisely, I'm simplifying a bit). With that in mind, let's deconstruct the above examples.

###### ~ inline example https://pl.kotl.in/VCwMsea_n

```kotlin
inline fun higherOrderFunction(lambda : () -> Unit) {
    lambda.invoke()
    println("test")
}
 
fun main() {
    higherOrderFunction {
        print("E Numbers Detector android app is the best")
        return
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to the below code if we could theoretically deconstruct the inline function into Kotlin code.

###### ~ deconstructed inline example https://pl.kotl.in/rbXgSnBlQ

```kotlin
fun main() {
    print("E Numbers Detector android app is the best")
    return    
    println("test")
}
```

As you can see the `return` makes the `main()` function to end and thus the "test" is never printed.

###### ~ crossinline example https://pl.kotl.in/bJdEm8QbR

```kotlin
inline fun higherOrderFunction(crossinline lambda : () -> Unit) {
    lambda.invoke()
    println("test")
}
 
fun testLambdaFunction() {
    println("E Numbers Detector android app is the best")
    return
    println("This code is unreachable")
} 
 
fun main() {
    higherOrderFunction {
        testLambdaFunction()
    }
}
```

As you can see this time the `return` ends the `testLambdaFunction()` not the `main()`.

###### ~ deconstructed crossinline example https://pl.kotl.in/6R3K7P21D

```kotlin
fun testLambdaFunction() {
    println("E Numbers Detector android app is the best")
    return
    println("This code is unreachable")
} 
 
fun main() {
    testLambdaFunction()
    println("test")
}
```

The `main()` function doesn't end until after printing "text", as there's no `return` called in it.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but I thimk that in both cases "return" is part of lambda we send, isn't it? So that definition us little bit confusing. Ok thanks for the answer!

Comment: I've edited my answer a bit to make the explanation clearer. Let me know if there's something I could clarify even further.

Comment: No everything fine, accepted!